# angularjs search filter on table with textbox based on dropdown selection

Tags: angularjs

I have a table, textbox and dropdown. I am able to search the table data based on dropdown selection and value of textbox. But in the middle of text search, if I change the dropdown selection, all data is not loading unless I totally keydown of my textbox. But my requirement is to load all data in the middle of search also so that I can search again without refreshing the page.

Here is the code:

```js
angular.module("myApp", [])
    .controller('myController', ['$scope', function ($scope) {

        $scope.employees = [
            { 'id': '001', 'name': 'Alpha', 'joinDate': '05/17/2015', 'age': 37 },
            { 'id': '002', 'name': 'Bravo', 'joinDate': '03/25/2016', 'age': 27 },
            { 'id': '003', 'name': 'Charlie', 'joinDate': '09/11/2015', 'age': 29 },
            { 'id': '004', 'name': 'Delta', 'joinDate': '09/11/2015', 'age': 19 },
            { 'id': '005', 'name': 'Echo', 'joinDate': '03/09/2014', 'age': 32 }
        ]

        // GET JSON ARRAY HEADERS.
        $scope.headers = Object.keys($scope.employees[0]);
    } ]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
<body>
    <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myController">
    
        <!--DYNAMICALLY POPULATE SELECT ELEMENT USING JSON HEADERS-->
        Search By 
        <select ng-init="columns=headers[1]" ng-model="columns" ng-options="e for e in headers"></select>
    
        <!--BIND THE SEARCH BOX TO THE SELECT ELEMENT-->
        Search <input type="text" ng-model="search[columns]" placeholder="Enter some text to search" />
    
        <table>
            <tr>
                <th>ID</th>
                <th>Employee Name</th>
                <th>Date of Joining</th>
                <th>Age</th>
            </tr>
            <tr ng-repeat="emps in employees | filter : search">
    
                <td>{{emps.id}}</td>
                <td>{{emps.name}}</td>
                <td>{{emps.joinDate | date : 'dd/MM/yyyy'}}</td>    
                <td>{{emps.age}}</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 2):

This can be handled easily by using ng-change in select tag.
Update the code with latest changes

```js
angular.module("myApp", [])
    .controller('myController', ['$scope', function ($scope) {

        $scope.employees = [
            { 'id': '001', 'name': 'Alpha', 'joinDate': '05/17/2015', 'age': 37 },
            { 'id': '002', 'name': 'Bravo', 'joinDate': '03/25/2016', 'age': 27 },
            { 'id': '003', 'name': 'Charlie', 'joinDate': '09/11/2015', 'age': 29 },
            { 'id': '004', 'name': 'Delta', 'joinDate': '09/11/2015', 'age': 19 },
            { 'id': '005', 'name': 'Echo', 'joinDate': '03/09/2014', 'age': 32 }
        ]

        // GET JSON ARRAY HEADERS.
        $scope.headers = Object.keys($scope.employees[0]);

        $scope.changeFilterTo = function(pr) {
          if ($scope.search) {
            //var value = "";
            for (var key in $scope.search) {
              if ($scope.search[key]) {
                //value = angular.copy($scope.search[key]);
                $scope.search[key] = undefined;
              }
            }
            //$scope.search[pr] = value;
          }
        }

        } ]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
<body>
    <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myController">
    
        <!--DYNAMICALLY POPULATE SELECT ELEMENT USING JSON HEADERS-->
        Search By 
        <select ng-init="columns=headers[1]" ng-model="columns" ng-options="e for e in headers" ng-change="changeFilterTo(columns)"></select>
    
        <!--BIND THE SEARCH BOX TO THE SELECT ELEMENT-->
        Search <input type="text" ng-model="search[columns]" placeholder="Enter some text to search" />
    
        <table>
            <tr>
                <th>ID</th>
                <th>Employee Name</th>
                <th>Date of Joining</th>
                <th>Age</th>
            </tr>
            <tr ng-repeat="emps in employees | filter : search">
    
                <td>{{emps.id}}</td>
                <td>{{emps.name}}</td>
                <td>{{emps.joinDate | date : 'dd/MM/yyyy'}}</td>    
                <td>{{emps.age}}</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Actually here onchange  select option in the middle of text(apart from the table) search,previous search is active but data is not loading,as per my requirement all data should be loaded onchange in the middle of text search.

Comment: Updated code - on select option change load all the iitems in table

Comment: Thanks Nishanth..This is really very useful for me.

Comment: Can I make the same thing with normal jquery without angularjs,here my table data will be coming from external json with ajax call

Comment: Please Accept/Vote for the answer if the question asked got the appropriate answer. And then create new question for the new requirement

Comment: It is possible via so amny jquery plugins. Refer this for example https://fooplugins.github.io/FooTable/

Comment: That is different,I need same as above example

Comment: Hi Nishanth,is there any other solution for this.